# Priority Verifier implementation in O(log(n))

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

A priority verifier support the operations, insert, delete, and not-all-bigger(z). The latter operation outputs “yes” provided there is an element currently in the set having key≤ z, an “no” otherwise. z is provided by the user. Can a priority verifier be implemented so that its operations have amortized cost o(log n) when there are n elements in the set?

Comment: I think this is something better suited to http://cs.stackexchange.com/, since this isn't really a question about code.

Comment: @Almo I think for simple questions it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Ok. It didn't look like a simple question to me, but I'm not a computer scientist. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with balanced trees, you have order, so you can find an element that is less than or equal to z by following the left path in the tree, going to the smaller and smaller element, note that the height of the tree is logarithmic, so it will take O(logn). All the other operations take O(logn) as well

Comment: But inserting to this tree would be nlogn

Comment: CMPS, inserting one element is logn, there are already n elements in the set

Comment: yeah inserting one element is logn but you have n elements, therefore nlogn

Comment: But that is not what the OP explained

Comment: @CMPS you can't insert n elements into anywhere in less than n steps, so obviously that's what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this question could be solved by using skip list. Since the insert/deletion are all log(n), and it could always maintain the largest guy in the set.